# How to manage authentication in a soap web service

Tags: java, web-services, authentication

I'm developing for the first time a Soap web service, using Axis2 upon Tomcat. 
What i need is to manage authentication. So, users, before calling rpc have to login. 
Now what I'm doing is storing into the DB a passFrase to give back users when they login, so I check if it exist and, if yes, the are allowed to call rpc. The matter is that this way is so inefficient.

Is there a way to handle users authentication easilier and more efficiently? Perhaps some library?

Comment: Possible doublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799921/how-to-authenticate-soap-based-java-web-services

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these three approaches:

1. Use transport level authentication such at BASIC or DIGEST AUTH, (and please use HTTPS here).
2. Use WS-Security (preferably WS-Policy) with a Username Token.
3. Handle it in the application layer (what you are doing now).

Depending on your demands/taste, choose one of the above that fulfill your needs the most.

I should warn you that as of today, (2) is not possible with the current stable release of Axis2 and Rampart (1.6.2), you have to use an earlier release (1.5.x), which I explained why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817145/axis2-user-authentication).